# I don't want the user to input !@##$%$#*& <-- these special characters in my TextField..How do I restrict this?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I don't want that the user can input these characters:

> ! @
>    $ % $ #
>   * &

<-- these special characters in my TextField.
How to restrict this in LWUIT?

Comment: No !@##$%$#*&ing clue.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a subclass and override insertChars or check the keypressed event.  When using the keypressed event you buffer the old input and when a bad character is entered you force the old value back into the control and send an error message to the user to stop them.  If you do not stop them it can get pretty flakey with the buffering and event delays.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to extend the TextField class and implement keyListener so that you "ignore" any of those characters when the user keys them in.

Here's a [good tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to exlude this characters and or you write some "little" parser on your own.